# How to instantiate a variable in prolog predicate

Tags: prolog, predicate

```
list([]) :- !.
list([A|B], X) :- X = X + 1, list(B, X).
```

I have the following predicate and I wish to determine the size of a list. In the second predicate, when I initially run into the predicate, X is not initialized. How can I check if X has a value before doing an increment it it.

```
?-list([a,b,c,d,e,f,g],X).
```

X should return 7 in this case

Comment: `=` is not an assignment operator in Prolog. It's unification. `X = X + 1` indicates you want to unify the variable `X` with the term `'+'(X,1)` which is a circular reference. If `X` is numeric, you can say, `X1 is X + 1` (note that `X is X + 1` would fail since the value of `X` cannot possibly be the value of `X+1`). And `list([]) :-...` is a problem. Where's the second argument? Your other predicate clause takes two arguments for `list`. I would also recommend *not* using a generic name list `list`. If you are defining a relation between a list and its length, why not call it `list_length`?

Comment: How about using the predefined predicate `length/2`?

Answer (score 0):

On declarative paradigms, instantiation is not possible (unless you use datafact or something similar), so a way to solve your issue would be by declaring that the empty list has size 0:

```
list([],0) :- !.
list([A|B], X1) :- list(B, X0), X1 = X0 + 1.
```

By that way, you know that the length of a list **L** is *1+(length of **L** tail)*

Answer (score -1):

In regards to this portion of Your sample code :

```
X = X + 1
```

A very common mistake for people new to Prolog .
The ``='' in Prolog means "is the same as" .
Therefore the code segment above is declaring "X is the same as X + 1" .
At the very least , it will have to be :

```
X = Y + 1
```

However that is not quite what You need , because :

```
?- Y = 2 , X = Y + 1  .
X = Y + 1
Y = 2
```

For getting Prolog to put the result of a maths calculation on the right-hand-side into a variable on the left-hand-side , use `_lhs_ is _rhs_`
.

```
?- Y = 2 , X is Y + 1  .
X = 3
Y = 2
```

In regards to the question

```
How can I check if X has a value before doing an increment to it.
```

`when(ground(_variable_),(_thing_to_do))` is the best of available options .

Here is an example solution to the overall problem posed that utilizes some those concepts .

#### implementation

```
goal_expansion((_lhs_ =:= _rhs_),(when(ground(_rhs_),(_lhs_ is _rhs_))))  .

:- op(2'1,'yfx','list')  .

_list_ list [size:_size_] :-
_list_ list [size:_size_,shrink:_shrink_] ,
_list_ list [size:_size_,shrink:_shrink_,size:_SIZE_]  .

_list_ list [size:0,shrink:false]  .

_list_ list [size:_size_,shrink:true] :-
when(ground(_size_),(_size_ > 0))  .

[] list [size:0,shrink:false,size:0] .

[_car_|_cdr_] list [size:_size_,shrink:true,size:_SIZE_] :-
(_SIZE_ =:= _size_ - 1) ,
(_size_ =:= _SIZE_ + 1) ,
_cdr_ list [size:_SIZE_]  .
```

#### testing

```
/*
   ?- L list Z .
L = [],
Z = [size:0] ? ;
L = [_A],
Z = [size:1] ? ;
L = [_A,_B],
Z = [size:2] ? ;
L = [_A,_B,_C],
Z = [size:3] ?
yes

   ?- L list [size:0] .
L = [] ? ;
no
   ?- L list [size:1] .
L = [_A] ? ;
no
   ?- L list [size:2] .
L = [_A,_B] ? ;
no

   ?- [] list [size:S] .
S = 0 ? ;
no
   ?- [a] list [size:S] .
S = 1 ? ;
no
   ?- [a,b] list [size:S] .
S = 2 ? ;
no
   ?- [a,b,c] list [size:S] .
S = 3 ? ;
no
   ?- 
*/
```

Comment: Are you aware of the builtin predicate `length/2`?